# Drag and Drop in to the DataGrid not working after project deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, drag

In my WPF application I have a DataGrid. I have successfully implemented Drag&Drop functionality. I can drop any file into it without any problems.
I then created Setup file for my application using Visual Studio Installer. When I install my application (even on the same computer) Drag&Drop no longer works. I found out that PreviewDragOver event is not firing, AllowDrop is set to true.

Do you have any idea why or any suggestion?

Comment: https://codeinreview.com/136/enabling-drag-and-drop-over-a-grid-in-wpf/ this might throw you some idea. Even i faced this issue sometime back and this one helped me out :) Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it but the problem is still the same. 
The problem is that everything works fine when debugging. It is not working after I install it. I'm not really sure how to start looking for a problem.